# AS3 - How to stop player when touching object using hitTestObject?

Tags: actionscript-3, keyboard-events, hittest, enterframeevent

I would like to know how to stop a the player when touching an object. I have movements set up here but I could not find a way to make my player properly stop when touching objects.

My player's movement code in the player `Class`:

This is the event listener for when the keys are pressed. The `Boolean` values become true when pressed.

```
public function onKeyDown(event:KeyboardEvent):void
{
    if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.D)
    {
        isRight = true;
    }
    if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.A)
    {
        isLeft = true;
    }
    if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.W)
    {
        isUp = true;
    }
    if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.S)
    {
        isDown = true;
    }
}
```

This is the the event listener for when the key are not pressed. The `Boolean` values become false when not pressed.

```
private function onKeyUp(event:KeyboardEvent):void
{
    if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.D)
    {
        isRight = false;
    }

    if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.A)
    {
        isLeft = false;
    }

    if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.W)
    {
        isUp = false;
    }

    if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.S)
    {
        isDown = false;;
    }

}
```

This is the enter frame, `vx` and `vy` are `int` variables and are 0 when keys are not pressed, but they change value when keys are pressed. The `vx` and `vy` also add to the player's `x` and `y` every frame but when they are 0, the player won't move.

```
private function onEnterFrame(event:Event):void
{
    _vx = 0;
    _vy = 0;

    if (isRight)
    {
        _vx = 5;
    }

    if (isLeft)
    {
        _vx = -5;
    }

    if (isUp)
    {
        _vy = -5;
    }

    if (isDown)
    {
        _vy = 5;
    }

    x += _vx;
    y += _vy;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to have many conditions, take a look at this example:

```
_keys = new Object();

_keys[Keyboard.D] = false;
_keys[Keyboard.A] = false;
_keys[Keyboard.W] = false;
_keys[Keyboard.S] = false;  

this.stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keyInteraction);
this.stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, keyInteraction);

//---Key events
function keyInteraction(evt:KeyboardEvent){

    if( _keys.hasOwnProperty(evt.keyCode) ){

        _keys[evt.keyCode] = Boolean( evt.type == KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN );

    }

}
```

When you press or release <kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>W</kbd>, <kbd>D</kbd> or <kbd>S</kbd> keys, the respective _keys `Object` properties changes from `true` to `false`.

Now, the `hitTest` part. Maybe is better the `hitTestPoint` method than the `hitestObject` method because this last one only checks if the bounds of both objects are touching.  While the `hitTestPoint` method checks if the `point` touches any of the pixels of the `Object`.

As you move the player every five pixels, it is necessary restore the player to correct position in which it no touch the object (I've made a `while` cycle for this purpose). Depends of your game design, you need to change the code, but this guide you in your purpose:

> The `maze` is the object that the `player` can't touch:

**Player's getPoint method**

```
public function getPoint(corner:uint){

    var point:Point = this.parent.localToGlobal( new Point( this.x, this.y ) );

    if(corner == 1 || corner == 2) point.x += _w;
    if(corner == 2 || corner == 3) point.y += _h;

    return point;

}
```

**HitTest Code (Game Tick)**

```
//---Move the player
private function gameTick(evt:Event):void{

    var hit:Boolean = false;

    //---Sum the vars horizontal
    if( _keys[Keyboard.D] ) _player.x += 5;
    if( _keys[Keyboard.A] ) _player.x -= 5;

    //---Check if the point is inside the scene in the horizontal
    if(_player.x < 0) _player.x = 0;
    if(_player.x > this.stage.stageWidth - _player.width) _player.x = this.stage.stageWidth - _player.width;            

    var TL:Point = _player.getPoint(0);
    var TR:Point = _player.getPoint(1);
    var BR:Point = _player.getPoint(2);
    var BL:Point = _player.getPoint(3);

    //---Hittest in the horizontal
    if(
        _maze.hitTestPoint(TL.x, TL.y, true)
        ||
        _maze.hitTestPoint(TR.x, TR.y, true)
        ||
        _maze.hitTestPoint(BR.x, BR.y, true)
        ||
        _maze.hitTestPoint(BL.x, BL.y, true)
    ){

        var sumX:int = 0;

        if( _keys[Keyboard.D] ) sumX = -1;
        if( _keys[Keyboard.A] ) sumX = 1;

        hit = true;

        while(hit){

            TL.x += sumX;
            TR.x += sumX;
            BR.x += sumX;
            BL.x += sumX;

            if(
                !_maze.hitTestPoint(TL.x, TL.y, true)
                &&
                !_maze.hitTestPoint(TR.x, TR.y, true)
                &&
                !_maze.hitTestPoint(BR.x, BR.y, true)
                &&
                !_maze.hitTestPoint(BL.x, BL.y, true)
            ){

                hit = false;

                _player.x = TL.x;

            }

        }

    }

    //---Sum the vars vertical
    if( _keys[Keyboard.S] ) _player.y += 5;
    if( _keys[Keyboard.W] ) _player.y -= 5;

    //---Check if the point is inside the scene in the vertical
    if(_player.y < 0) _player.y = 0;
    if(_player.y > this.stage.stageHeight - _player.height) _player.y = this.stage.stageHeight - _player.height;            

    TL = _player.getPoint(0);
    TR = _player.getPoint(1);
    BR = _player.getPoint(2);
    BL = _player.getPoint(3);

    if(
        _maze.hitTestPoint(TL.x, TL.y, true)
        ||
        _maze.hitTestPoint(TR.x, TR.y, true)
        ||
        _maze.hitTestPoint(BR.x, BR.y, true)
        ||
        _maze.hitTestPoint(BL.x, BL.y, true)
    ){

        var sumY:int = 0;

        if( _keys[Keyboard.S] ) sumY = -1;
        if( _keys[Keyboard.W] ) sumY = 1;

        hit = true;

        while(hit){

            TL.y += sumY;
            TR.y += sumY;
            BR.y += sumY;
            BL.y += sumY;

            if(
                !_maze.hitTestPoint(TL.x, TL.y, true)
                &&
                !_maze.hitTestPoint(TR.x, TR.y, true)
                &&
                !_maze.hitTestPoint(BR.x, BR.y, true)
                &&
                !_maze.hitTestPoint(BL.x, BL.y, true)
            ){

                hit = false;

                _player.y = TL.y;

            }

        }

    }

}
```

[Download the example](http://xprimiendo.com/examples/FLASH/MazeGame.zip)

Comment: Is it possible to allow it to still move forward and backward when only colliding on the x points, and can move left to right when it's colliding only on the y points?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. That is what the example does.

Comment: Well one issue I caught is that if the player has the up or down key held, and then try to move left or right, it will stay at the same spot.

Comment: That is the expected behavior in every 2D game. For example, UP + RIGHT is diagonal movement, if the player can't move to the right he shouldn't move diagonally-right either. And if the player can't move forward he shouldn't move diagonally-right either.

Comment: But, when the player presses the UP key and RIGHT key while colliding, the player should stop moving up, but could still move right.

Comment: It is not hard to figure it out. In this case you only need do the checks horizontal or vertical movement separately. I'll edit the post.

Answer (score 1):

Add another condition & set the incrementors _vx or _vy (or both) to 0 after the the conditions checking for the key states in **onEnterFrame**.

```
if(player.hitTestObject(object)){
        _vx = 0;
        _vy = 0;
}
```

Comment: But that would stop both horizontal and vertical movement. I would need my player to actually stop x movement when touching the left and right sides but can still move up and down. Then if it touches the top or bottom, it can still move left and right.

Comment: Ofcourse.. that's upto you how you wish to implement the logic. So now you could use `hittTestPoint` instead of `hitTestObject` & check for the four points you just mentioned. 2 of them would reset `_vx` & the other 2 `_vy`.

Comment: That makes sense. Do you have a small link or example for setting up hitTestPoint?

Answer (score 0):

```
if(player.hitTestObject(object)){
     // stop player
    player.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEnterFrame);
}
```

or you can do the other way around.
put this inside your enterframe of your player.